# Playstation Plus account for a *child* account? (PS4)

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I'm looking to get a Playstation Plus account for my eldest. I have setup a Family and my PSN account is the "parent" account. I am aware that if I activate the PS+ subscription on "my" account, I can share it with the rest of the accounts in the PS4 and they'll have some of the privileges... *BUT* given that I don't play, I think it'd be best if he had access to all the features including cloud saves etc.

So the question is:

1. Can a child have a PS+ sub when the "parent" doesn't?
2. Can a child have the PS4 as primary so the rest of the accounts have the (partial/shared) PS+ benefits?

Thanks!